# How can I get the total amount of specific pixel fires in a given time period using Facebooks Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I'm making an analytics dashboard and want to see how many of my pixel fires are from ads and how many are from organic traffic.

I can easily get the amount of pixel fires from my ads by using AdInsights, however, I can't seem to find a way to get the total amount of pixel fires.

This is my code so far. It only return the pixel objects with some basic fields like name, ID and when it was fired last. I want to know how many times they've fired.

```
$account = new AdAccount('ACT_ID');

$pixels = $account->getAdsPixels(array(
    AdsPixelFields::NAME,
    AdsPixelFields::ID,
    AdsPixelFields::LAST_FIRED_TIME
));
```

Answer (score 0):

pixelstats node can provide more information about the pixel firing
for example you can get device types in the last 24 hours, it will give you the number of pixel fires under specific devices

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdsPixel;

$pixel = new AdsPixel(<PIXEL_ID>);
$pixel->getStats(array(), array(
  'aggregation' => 'device_type',
));
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/conversion-tracking/v2.9